# How to insert Case Sensitive Login Name for a Sharepoint User

Tags: claims-based-auth, user, login

I'm in a claim based installation of sharepoint 2010. My users are matched by user GUID in this form:

provider|GUID@mydomain.dom

My GUID is case sensitive.

If I use SPEnsureUser(provider|GUID@mydomain.dom) it creates the user but with lowercase login name!

I tried AddUser(provider|GUID@mydomain.dom, mail, name, note) but the user has a lowercase login name.

With SPFarm.local.MigrateUser( lower --> normal case) the login name comes as I want it.

There is any other way to create new user on sharepoint?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://snipplr.com/view/25015/

Comment: Yes but takes me to a case insensitive login name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457529.aspx

SharePoint Foundation does not support working with a case-sensitive membership provider. It uses case-insensitive SQL storage for all users in the database, regardless of the membership provider.

So even if a login name is registered as lowercase or uppercase to sharepoint it is the same.